# How to pause template rendering to update underlying model?

Tags: ember.js

Currently I have controller field that contains Mutable Array full of objects.
Each time i add/remove elements in array - template rendering occurs. That is good.

And now i have a situation, where I have to replace whole array.

If I do this via `.clear()` and then `.pushObjects()` I see template flickering.

It is pretty noticeable, because Em render empty template at `.clear` and render template again, 
after `.pushObjects()` call.

I thought, is there any way to pause template rendering while model is updating? 
In this case should be only one render call, and flickering shouldn't be.

So question is: how to control rendering process in Ember?

Answer (score 0):

Ember will update your template when you call the `set` method. For example, in one of your controller functions, you may do something like this:

```
var someArray = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
this.set('myArray', someArray);
```

This will cause anything binding to `myArray` to update. In your case, I would get your array, do your modifications (`clear` and `pushObjects`), then call `set`:

```
var arr = this.get('myArray');
arr.clear();
arr.pushObjects(...);
this.set('myArray', arr);
```

Comment: I think when you get reference to myArray and do .clear and .pushObjects will cause re-rendering each time because observers still attached to mutable array.

Comment: Can you look at [this jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/badoci/20/edit) and let me know how yours differs?

Comment: I understood you, in this solution you don't see flickering because you just don't have much html over there. If you have complicated template - you definitely will see laggs.

Comment: It's more likely that you observe binding/rendering big bulk of data problem (which is pain in Ember) than anything else. I'd recommend to consider use of CloakedView or Ember.ListView for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Ember uses [run loop](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/applications/run-loop/) and queues to avoid described problem. Do you change the array (clean & fulfill) in a synchronous way?

Comment: `var controller = App.__container__.lookup('controller:MyController');
var options = controller.get('options');
options.clear();
var objects = [{
    //obj1
},
{
    //obj2
},
{
    //obj3
}];

options.pushObjects(objects);`

I need update model from outside of ember framework.